# OpenTok accessDenied issue in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, opentok, tokbox

I'm having some trouble with the [OpenTok 2 API](https://tokbox.com/opentok/libraries/client/js/reference/Publisher.html). When I start to publish a stream and I'm prompted to allow or deny the website to use my webcam and microphone, if I allow allowed() should run, but if I deny denied() should run.

```
publisher.addEventListener('accessAllowed', allowed);
publisher.addEventListener('accessDenied', denied);

function allowed() {
    console.log('Allowed');
}

function denied() {
    console.log('Denied');
}
```

It works as expected in Firefox. In Chrome accessAllowed works, however, accessDenied doesn't. Instead I get the following error:

```
OT.Publisher.onStreamAvailableError PermissionDeniedError:
TB.exception :: title: Internal Error (2000) msg: Publisher failed to access camera/mic:
```

Any ideas?

Comment: engineer at tokbox here. i've been able to reproduce this issue and i am filing a bug internally. i'll come back and answer this question when it is fixed but i'll also suggest a workaround below.

Answer (score 5):

This is a bug in the current JS library at OpenTok. I do have a workaround that should get you going and I'll come back with an update when the bug is fixed.

```
var waiting = false;
publisher.addEventListener('accessAllowed', function() {
  waiting = false;
  allowed();
});
publisher.addEventListener('accessDenied', function() {
  waiting = false;
  denied();
});
publisher.addEventListener('accessDialogOpened', function() {
  waiting = true;
});
publisher.addEventListener('accessDialogClosed', function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    if (waiting) {
      waiting = false;
      denied();
    }
  }, 0);
});
```

This workaround is slightly limited because Chrome has some weirdness when it comes to denying access once and then visiting the page again. If the user hasn't changed his/her preferences regarding the media permissions, the video will continue to be denied and the 'accessDialogOpened' won't even fire. I'll inform the team and continue to look into this.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Let me know when the bug is fixed.

Comment: Please post a link to issue in chromium if there exists one

Comment: @Ankur, any progress here on opentok side?