# Javascript TokBox videochat denied on Chrome

Tags: javascript, php, google-chrome, opentok, tokbox

I have a problem with TokBox, it's working very well in all browser but in Chrome i receive this error in console

> OT.Publisher.onStreamAvailableError Permission Denied
>
> Session.publish :: OT.Publisher Access Denied: Permission Denied:
>   End-user denied permission to hardware devices

I put a control in my PHP page like this:

```
publisher.on({
accessAllowed: function (event) {
// User has active camera or microphone
$("#chat-end").css("display","block");
console.log("publisher active");
},
accessDenied: function accessDeniedHandler(event) {
// The user has denied access to the camera and mic.
alert('Sessione bloccata, devi consentire al tuo browser di accedere a webcam e microfono');
console.log("blocked");
}
});
```

Only in chrome i receive the error ***console.log("blocked");***
Why?
Any Suggestions?

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21559016/opentok-accessdenied-issue-in-chrome

Comment: @Omix22 Hi, i see this page but i tried the code in the answer and not work...